# Are there any examples of recreating SHODAN's voice effect?

Tags: system-shock

All of this Portal 2 talk has caused me to return to System Shock 2 to hear SHODAN.

Are there any tutorials detailing how that voice effect was made?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, first they started by hiring [Terri Brosius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terri_Brosius), who has a truly amazing voice. Then the voice was

> accompanied by *[stuttering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuttering)*, *fluctuating*
>    *voice*  *[pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_%28music%29)*, shifts of *[timbre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre)*, and the
>   presence of three voices speaking the
>   same words with the constituent voices
>   alternately lagging behind and leading
>   ahead, as well as computer glitches
>   resembling a sound card malfunction.

From the [SHODAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHODAN) wikipedia entry.

Update: also, if you want a good audio-editor package, [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is amazing - and open-source.